# How to add multiple images to a single product in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, spree

I want to add the ability on spree to assign multiple images for the same product.

From your experience, what is the best way to do this ? Is there any spree extension for this ? ( Before i develop something from scratch...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Spree already supports multiple images.  Just assign them in the admin panel. https://guides.spreecommerce.com/user/creating_products.html#images